# Habakkuk 3:13 what does it say?

Tags: commentaries, chabakuk--book-of

Looking at the words יצאת לישע עמך לישע את משיחך from Habakkuk 3:13, I noticed it was translated as: ‘Thou art come forth for the deliverance of Thy people, for the deliverance of Thine anointed (mechon-mamre translation)’, and as ‘You have come forth to deliver Your people, to deliver Your anointed (sefaria translation). Thus referring to Israel two times. While it could also be understood to mean that Adonai will come forth to deliver His people (Israel), to deliver with His Mashiach.

Are there any commentaries claiming G-d will come to the rescue/aid/deliverance with His Messiah, according to Habakkuk?

Comment: +1 (Not sure that isn't the simpler interpretation of e.g. Rashi and Radak.)

Comment: a question asking for "any commentaries" is difficult to answer definitively. I have yet to find one that sees "et" as "with" but there are always others.

Answer (score -1):

In summation it does not mean that the Mashiach will save Bnai Yisrael, but that Hashem will save the Mashiach. See the references below.

[Chavakuk 3:13](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16199/showrashi/true#v13) shows the JPS translation as

> You went forth to rescue Your people, to rescue Your anointed. You
>   have crushed the head of the house of the wicked, uncovering it from
>   the foundation to the neck-forever.

Rashi explains

> **to rescue Your anointed**: Saul and David.

Thus the meaning according to Rashi is that the first rescue is about the people in general while the second is the rescue of those who had been anointed as the leaders of the people. I do not see the usage that you suggest of recue the people via the anointed. Additionally, both are in the past tense not the future tense so it does not refer to the mashiach.

There are [others](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Chavakkuk/3.13#e0n6)

Ibn Ezra says

> לישע את משיחך – מלך יהודה.

Radak and Malbim do say

> משיחך כי אז יתגלה המלך המשיח וילחם מלחמות ה׳ וה׳ יושיעהו

Then the identity of the Mashiach will be revealed and he will fight the wars of Hashem and Hashem will save him.

Comment: So your answer is "no, there aren't"?

Comment: @msh210 I added a summary at the top explaining that it means that Hashem will save the mashiach not that the mashiach will save the people. I showed the meforshim who say that it refers to the kings who preceded Chavakuk and others who say it refers to the mashiach ben David in the future.

Comment: So your answer is "no, there aren't"?

Comment: @msh210 Correct. I did not find any commentaries that seemed to say that the Mashiach would save Israel. All the commentaries that referenced the mashiach translated it as Hashem would save the Mashiach. The others said that Hashem had saved those who had been anointed as king (in the past)